# How to change the font-color of jQuery Full-calendar header title?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I'm using the [jQuery full-calender](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/header/) for my work. As in the image I have created the calendar but now I want to change the title color of the header (`February 2015`) to green. (to match it to the theme)

[image]

[image]

So far I couldn't do that. I saw some SO questions and answers which are suggesting to change the `.css` file. But then the change will affect to all calendars (`I'm having several calendars with several themes`)

How can I solve  this problem ?

**UPDATE** :

This is an example code [in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prime/DLXLR/2/).

Comment: any fiddle example please

Comment: You should look at the div that's nesting the h2, In this case I think it's the jquery-ui div. The background color could be set as part of jquery-ui Instead of the calendar ext.

Comment: And indeed, a fiddle would be nice XD

Comment: Add the rule `#expandedCalender .fc-toolbar { color: ... }` after the calendar stylesheet (`fullcalendar.min.css`)

Comment: one way is #expandedCalender .fc-center h2{color:#0f0}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solutions for this one is

CSS

```
div#fullcalendar .fc-header-title h2 {
    color: #0F0;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nadeemmnn2007/DLXLR/3/)

which will does the work.

as per your fiddle example

and every Calender ID will be unique, so you can add

```
div#CalenderName .fc-header-title h2 {
    color: #0F0; //change calender title Color accordingly
}
```

for example **`calender1`** is your calender id then in CSS

```
div#calender1 .fc-header-title h2 {
    color: #0F0; //change calender title Color accordingly
}
```

and for example **`calender2`** is your calender id then in CSS

```
div#calender2 .fc-header-title h2 {
    color: #0F0; //change calender title Color accordingly
}
```

Comment: Rate it if you find my answer useful

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom class that overrides the font color, then add it to only the specific calendar you want to override.

It'll look something like this (since you didn't provide any code).

style.css

```
.override-font-color {
    font-color: #fff;
}
```

index.html

```
<div class="calendar-theme-header override-font-color">February 2015</div>
```

Comment: As it will generate dynamically cannot be used

Comment: the div will be generated at run time / dynamically :/