# Changing header title color in Full Calendar 2.3.2

Tags: css, colors, header, fullcalendar, title

This answer appears to be out of date as the stylesheet is now different:

[how-to-change-the-font-color-of-jquery-full-calender-header-title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387659/how-to-change-the-font-color-of-jquery-full-calender-header-title)

How do i do this for version 2.3.2 of FullCalendar?

With thanks.

Comment: place some code please

Answer (score 1):

After much searching, I have found the relevant section of code. In version 2.3.2 it resides at line 710 of fullcalendar.css

```
/* title text */
.fc-toolbar h2 {
margin: 0;
color: #FFF;
}
```